# .NET MVC 3 (C#) default membership provider - how to set up?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm somewhat confused by membership providers for .NET. I have built a MVC 3 web application, but obviously login pages don't work out-of-the-box because I need to wire up a membership provider. I would have expected this process to be easy, but when I search for help I find numerous articles on writing custom providers. Can't I just set up a table or two, wire up a few details in web.config and have things work based on some default MVC membership provider?

I have no desire to re-invent the wheel!

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The MSDN membership installation documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) is still applicable through to .NET 4, although note that the default Membership provider changes in 4.5 - totally different table structures.

**TL;DR**

- Create the aspnet membership database *OR* add the tables to your existing database (`aspnet_regsql.exe`, which is in the .net 2 framework folder)
- Add the necessary membership and role provider configuration sections to your web.config.
- Use the site admin tool to add users (or at least an initial Admin User)