# How to use membership authorization in C#?

Tags: c#, membership

I'm trying to figure out how to use membership authorization.
When I put in my web.config `<authorization>` and in my controller I validate it, it doesn't work. When I enter in my page login doesn't show me nothing. If I remove `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` and `<authorization>`, it show normally

**web.config**

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Paginas/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

  <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator" />
      <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
```

**PaginasController**

```
    namespace ControleBU.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public class PaginasController : Controller
        {
             .
             .
             .
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, means what exactly?

Comment: When I enter in my page login not show me nothing. If I remove [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] and <authorization>, it show normally

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET MVC 3 (C#) default membership provider - how to set up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391506/net-mvc-3-c-default-membership-provider-how-to-set-up)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate

Comment: You most probably haven't setup the authorization database properly. The linked possible duplicate explains how to set up what's needed.